# how to change the default positioning of modal in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

how can I change the default modal position in bootstrap, where should I edit to change the default position.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053408/vertically-centering-bootstrap-modal-window...  might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Add the following css to your html and try changing the top, right, bottom, left values.

```
.modal {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   right: 100px;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 10040;
   overflow: auto;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: how can er make the background of modal transparent instead of the black one .

Comment: opacity: 1; or addclass 'fade'

Comment: isn't there any way to remove the black transparent color and make the modal to pop up without any effect?what if i want just the modal to appear without any effect?

Comment: override the 'modal-backdrop' css, change the opacity : 0;

Answer (score 20):

I get a better result setting this class:

```
.modal-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10040;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

With bootstrap 3.3.7.

(all credits to msnfreaky for the idea...)

Comment: This worked for me using boostrap 3.3.7, the accepted answer didn't.

Comment: I tried this for some python/Dash development ... It is working like a charm !

Answer (score 7):

If you need to change the bottom position of the modal, you need to modify the max-height of the modal-body:

```css
.modal-body {
  max-height: 75vh;
}
```

As other answers have said, you can adjust the right and top on the modal-dialog :

```css
.modal-dialog {
  top: 10vh;
  right: 5vw;
}
```

- "vh" means "% of view height"
- "vw" means "% of view width"

Answer (score 6):

To change the Modal position in the viewport you can target the Modal div id, in this example this id is myModal3

```
    <div id="modal3" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


#myModal3 {
top:5%;
right:50%;
outline: none;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: side bar aapears at middle how do we hide it

Comment: have overflow:hidden in the css. Updated the css class #myModal3

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap 5, just add this to your css.

```
  .modal-dialog { top: 7rem !important; }
```

Do not add to `.modal` otherwise the modal will not be dismissed when tapping on the top of the modal because backdrop is shifted down too.

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS file add following lines:

```css
.modal-dialog {
  transform: translateY(50%)!important;
}
```

You can change `50%` to any other value, which will solve the problem in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 5 there is two options to open modal in center. No need to add any custom CSS.

1. Vertically centered modal

```html
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
  ...
</div>
```

2. Vertically centered scrollable modal

```html
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
  ...
</div>
```

I hope this will help too.

Answer (score -6):

I know it's a bit late but I had issues with a modal window not allowing some links on the menu bar to work, even when it has not been triggered. But I solved it by doing the following:

```
.modal{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: If you can't solve the issue, add ```display: none``` to it. Bravo!