# How to center modal to the center of screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to center modal to the center of screen?
This is my html and js code
It works in Chrome console, but when I refresh this page - it doesn't work

```
$('.modal').css('top', $(window).outerHeight() / 2 - ($(".modal-dialog").outerHeight()) / 2 + 'px');
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap ? If yes, [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053408/vertically-centering-bootstrap-modal-window)

Comment: Pure JavaScript  :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62282447/11258866

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Easy way to solve

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: The result is a blurry text.

Comment: If one has too much content in the div and you dont want it's top sticking out the frame, you should add `max-height: 90%;` it worked for me

Answer (score 26):

There is no need for **jQuery**, you can accomplish that just using css:

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

.modal {
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

If you prefer **jQuery** solution here is it:

```js
$(function() {
  var modal = $(".modal");
  var body = $(window);
  // Get modal size
  var w = modal.width();
  var h = modal.height();
  // Get window size
  var bw = body.width();
  var bh = body.height();
  
  // Update the css and center the modal on screen
  modal.css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": ((bh - h) / 2) + "px",
    "left": ((bw - w) / 2) + "px"
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

.modal {
  background: green;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Comment: `Float: left`? :)

Comment: as I scroll, the modal doesn't move - it doesn't remain in the center of the viewport

Answer (score 8):

Try like this

```
.modal {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0!important;
}

.modal:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.modal-dialog {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

if you prefer jquery means try this

```
function setModalMaxHeight(element) {
  this.$element     = $(element);  
  this.$content     = this.$element.find('.modal-content');
  var borderWidth   = this.$content.outerHeight() - this.$content.innerHeight();
  var dialogMargin  = $(window).width() < 768 ? 20 : 60;
  var contentHeight = $(window).height() - (dialogMargin + borderWidth);
  var headerHeight  = this.$element.find('.modal-header').outerHeight() || 0;
  var footerHeight  = this.$element.find('.modal-footer').outerHeight() || 0;
  var maxHeight     = contentHeight - (headerHeight + footerHeight);

  this.$content.css({
      'overflow': 'hidden'
  });

  this.$element
    .find('.modal-body').css({
      'max-height': maxHeight,
      'overflow-y': 'auto'
  });
}

$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
  $(this).show();
  setModalMaxHeight(this);
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($('.modal.in').length != 0) {
    setModalMaxHeight($('.modal.in'));
  }
});
```

Comment: The CSS only solutions is what works for me. Very neat!

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Bootstrap modals, all you need to do is add the .modal-dialog-centered class to the modal dialog. See below

Change this line `<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">`

To this line `<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">`

Answer (score 4):

Centering the modal is fairly simple if you use the CSS calc() function on the left CSS property. Let's say that the modal has a width of 600px. You can use 50% of the screen width minus half of the width for the modal. This example below has the modal at 600px so I have the calc() function at 50% - 300px.

```
#modal {
   position:  fixed;
   width: 600px;
   top: 40px;
   left: calc(50% - 300px);
   bottom: 40px;
   z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: this css is not working

Comment: @RohanDevaki - do you have any conflicting styles. I use the CSS calc function all the time without a problem. If you are centering vertically, you may need to change "50%" to (50vh) in the calc function

Comment: @JayJara This is not a proper solution, this is only for horizontal alignment of fixed width. What about the height? What if modals have dynamic content? Also, what about responsiveness and mobile users?

Answer (score 3):

you should rewrite the css class for modals and modals dialog as this :

```
.modal-dialog {
  display: flex !important;
  width: 50% !important;
  pointer-events: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.modal{
  display:flex !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

simply add below class "modal-dialog-centered" like below

```
<div class="modal center" tabindex="-1" id="tourBookModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
       <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The best solution without any specific css and mathematical calculations

Answer (score 2):

**Pure Javascript**

This code helps you in all scenarios

```
 var setDivCenter = function (classORid) {

        var div = document.querySelector(classORid);

        var Mwidth = div.offsetWidth;
        var Mheight = div.offsetHeight;
        var Wwidth = window.innerWidth;
        var Wheight = window.innerHeight;

        div.style.position = "absolute";
        div.style.top = ((Wheight - Mheight ) / 2 +window.pageYOffset ) + "px";
        div.style.left = ((Wwidth - Mwidth) / 2 +window.pageXOffset ) + "px";

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in js file.
Note: 
     "#mydialog" change to your selector(Dialog class or ID)

```js
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function(event) {
        $('#mydialog').position({
                my: 'center',
                at: 'center',
                of: window,
                collision: 'fit'
          });
     });
});
```

Thanks,
Anand.

Comment: The position method in jQuery doesn't accept arguments. Here's a JS Bin demonstrating your code in action. http://jsbin.com/?js,console,output please amend or update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
.modal-dialog {
  height: 100%;
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-content {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: High quality code-only answers should come with at least a little bit of supporting text explaining how your code solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this it works.

```
.modal-dialog {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$('.modal').css('margin-top', (Math.floor((window.innerHeight - $('.modal')[0].offsetHeight) / 2) + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Get the modal
const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
const btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
const span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: flex;/* Hidden by default */
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
```