# center div regardless of changing browser zoom

Tags: javascript, css

I have a modal that I resized and looks like this at zoom 80% of my browser:

[image: Modal]

My problem is when I increase or decrease my browser zoom, my modal does not adjust automatically with my browser zoom and it becomes like this :

[image: Modal not centered]

Here is my CSS code :

```
.resizeModal {
    width: 99vw;
    right: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Is there anyway to automatically center my interface whether I increase or decrease my browser zoom?

Comment: Did you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121150/css-centering-with-transform) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39636815/7186622)?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the **margin auto** to automatically center:

```
.resizeModal {
    width: 99vw;
    right: 500px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
```

If the first method doesn't work for you, you can combine it with **position absolute** and all borders to 0 as follows:
position: absolute;  /* Position the element absolutely */

```
  .resizeModal {
        width: 99vw;
        position: absolute; 
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it does not change anything :(