# How to vertically align Bootstrap v4 modal dialogs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Vertically center modal dialogues in Bootstrap 4.

**Note:** The requirements below have been added to make it clear I am looking for a ***proper*** way to vertically center a Bootstrap modal, covering all possible cases, on all possible devices, in all browsers. In my case, I wanted it for a large SPA reusing the same modal throughout the app so I needed it to work in each case.

It should:

- keep modal contents accessible, on all devices, even when taller than device height
- work on any device+browser combination with a market share larger than `1%`
- not use `display:table-cell` or similar hacks (any layout-ing technique not meant or designed for layout-ing)
- close on `click` or `tap` anywhere outside of `.modal-content` (including above and below).
- limit usage of jQuery/JavaScript as much as possible
- (optional) work on default Bootstrap examples without need of **markup** modifications

Comment: @ZimSystem, this question is **not** a duplicate. It was asked 2 months prior to the "original". Besides, it has clear requirements which your answer does not meet. Additionally, your answer is wrong, technically. Modals taller than the viewport height will have their top part cut off and inaccessible. Try with a modal of `200vh` height and you'll understand.

Comment: as it says "possible dup". Also, as of Beta 3 there is a new `modal-dialog-centered` class.

Comment: @ZimSystem, please explain how an older question could "possibly 
 duplicate" a newer one. Thanks for the update on Bootstrap methods. I've updated the answer. Cheers!

Comment: OFC you can see it whatever way you like, but I mark dups to help users find answers in the future. Based on the title this question is generic, but the description outlines specific v center req's. I suggested the other answer as a solution that may or may not work in all cases, not to draw attention to my answer. I encountered this when answering the other as I always look for dups before answering. Since it wasn't an exact dup I pointed after I answered. Now the questions are linked hopefully it prevents another user asking another v center bootstrap 4 modal question.

Comment: The specific requirements were added to prevent answers that did not cover all cases (i.e.: long content requiring scroll) and low quality answers using `display:table`. You can sum all requirements in one word **proper** vertical centering a modal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I vertically center a div element for all browsers using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-can-i-vertically-center-a-div-element-for-all-browsers-using-css)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I center elements horizontally or vertically with Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088706/how-can-i-center-elements-horizontally-or-vertically-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: @TylerH, don't you think in order for a question to be a duplicate of another the original one has to have been asked first?

Comment: To clarify: the questions you marked as possible "originals" of mine are not, as none of them provides an answer on how to vertically and horizontally center a modal in Bootstrap v4. When I asked my question, this question had no answer on SO. However, after your vote, my question got closed as a dupe of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388989/bootstrap-center-vertical-and-horizontal-alignment), which was asked after mine.

Comment: @tao Age is only one factor (and not the most important) in dupe closure direction. More important are the scope of the question, quality of the answers, searchability (views, in essence), and more. Unfortunately I wasn't on the site at the time the question actually got closed, or I could have added the other two canonicals (both of which are older than this one, btw) to this multi-duplicate question. The CSS tag unfortunately wasn't used originally; had it been, I could have dupe-hammered this with all three targets myself immediately.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Update, as of Beta 3, [[docs]](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/):

> Add `.modal-dialog-centered` to `.modal-dialog` to vertically center the modal.

---

Original answer:

`SCSS`:

```css
.modal-dialog {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
  @media(max-width: 768px) {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  }
}
```

or **unprefixed** `CSS`:

```css
.modal-dialog {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  }
}
```

**Note 1:** Please note *fully prefixed* CSS gradually becomes obsolete as browser support for certain properties changes. The right way of getting the updated prefixed CSS is to:

- copy/paste the unprefixed CSS into [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).
- set the filter in the bottom box to the desired setting (for max. browser support use `> 0%`).
- get the latest code from the box on the right.

  ---

**Note 2:** This answer was added in early stages of **v4**  (*alpha 3 or 4*), which is now currently in *beta*. You can safely replace the CSS part of this answer by adding the following classes to `.modal-dialog`:

```
h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center my-0
```

..., as pointed out by @Androbaut in the comment below. You will still need the JavaScript (see below) to close the modal window on `click tap` below/above the modal window.

---

`jQuery` (needed to close modal on click/tap above/below):

```js
$('.modal-dialog').on('click tap', function(e){
  if ($(e.target).hasClass('modal-dialog')) {
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
  }
})
```

That's it.

---

Working snippet, fully-prefixed CSS and markup using different modal sizes:

```js
$('.modal-dialog').on('click tap', function(e){
  if ($(e.target).hasClass('modal-dialog')) {
   $('.modal').modal('hide');
  }
})
```

```css
.modal-dialog {
  min-height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 60px);
  min-height: -moz-calc(100vh - 60px);
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
     -moz-box-orient: vertical;
     -moz-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
     -moz-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto; 
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 20px);
    min-height: -moz-calc(100vh - 20px);
    min-height: calc(100vh - 20px);   
  }
}

/* you don't need the CSS below this line. It's mainly cosmetic and for aligning the modal launch buttons */

.modal-content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
     -moz-box-orient: vertical;
     -moz-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column; }
.modal-content > * {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
     -moz-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
          flex: 0 0 auto; 
}
.modal-content > *.modal-body {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
     -moz-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1; 
}

#Modal_2 .modal-content {
  min-height: 50vh; 
}

#Modal_3 .modal-content {
  min-height: 85vh; 
}

#Modal_4 .modal-content {
  min-height: 200vh; 
}

.full-page-center {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
     -moz-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
     -moz-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh; 
}
.full-page-center button {
  margin: 15px; 
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .full-page-center {
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;   
  }
  .full-page-center button {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 15px;
  }
  .full-page-center::after {
    display: none;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
       -moz-box-flex: 0;
        -ms-flex-positive: 0;
            flex-grow: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container full-page-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal_1">
    Tiny modal
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal_2">
    Normal modal
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal_3">
    Large modal
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal_4">
    Very large modal
  </button>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal_1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel_1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel_1">Tiny modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        I am cute...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal_2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel_2" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel_2">Dull modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        I am normal...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Some action</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal_3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel_3" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel_3">Don't call me fat</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Call me "oversized".
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Some action</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal_4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel_4" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel_4">Huge modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Comments, anyone?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Some action</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you find any bugs or shortcomings please let me know. I will take the time to improve the answer and keep it useful. Help with this task is welcome.

Comment: This can also be done using Bootstrap 4's built-in classes:
`div class="modal-dialog h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center my-0"`
Lets me avoid using `calc` & media queries.

Comment: As of Bootstrap 4 beta 2, you no longer need JavaScript to close when clicking above/below. See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/22704

Answer (score 13):

Simply add modal-dialog-centered class along with model-dialog as below

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
 <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal">Launch Modal</button>     
<div class="modal align-middle" id="MyModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h5>
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the                        printing and typesetting industry</div> 
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple Flexbox Approach.

**SCSS**

```
.modal-open .modal {
    display: flex!important;
    align-items: center!important;
    .modal-dialog {
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
}
```

[**Working Demo**](https://codepen.io/surjithctly/pen/dzOWQw)

Comment: This approach will cause the modal's top and bottom to go off-screen when you have a lot of content (e.g. BS4 beta's long scrolling demo).

Comment: your example works well bootstrap4 but has a little bug, you need to put off .modal-dialog { flex-grow: 1; } for 100% width on mobile.

Answer (score 5):

Just use this class " modal-dialog-centered " 
for showing Modal on center of screen Vertically .

for exmaple:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This solution works for small and long modals thats needs scroll.

Add these custom css rules:

```
.modal-header {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.modal-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And add these classes:

- To `modal-dialog`: `h-100 my-0 mx-auto d-flex flex-column justify-content-center`
- To `modal-content`: `m-2`

Like this:

```
<div class="modal-dialog h-100 my-0 mx-auto d-flex flex-column justify-content-center" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content m-2">
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add .modal-dialog-centered to .modal-dialog to vertically center the modal.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

By adding following css to '**.modal-dialog**' class, it works fine for me. You can override with custom css class also.

```
.modal-dialog {
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way to make your modal vertical align is to adjust `top: 50%;`, `transform: translateY(-50%);` and `margin: 0 auto` to the modal dialog class.

**Edit:**
The downside is that you also have to set `max-height: 100vh;` to `.modal-content`. Otherwise the top of modal is not accessible anymore when your modal is getting heigher than the viewport.

**Demo:**

```css
.modal.vertically-modal .modal-dialog {
  transform: translateY(-25%);
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.modal.vertically-modal.show .modal-dialog {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.modal-content {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".vertically-modal">Show modal</button>

<div class="modal fade vertically-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Vertically modal
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Except when the modal is taller than the viewport, in which case, the top part of the modal becomes inaccessible.

Comment: Yes thanks, I just noticed. Applying this style has only sense on a tablet or desktop. Normally you don't need to have your modal vertically aligned on a mobile device.

Comment: You have the exact same problem on desktop and tablet: if the modal is higher than `100vh` you can't scroll its top into view. With absolute centering method, when you place a taller child inside a parent with `overflow:auto` (like `<body>`), you lose the ability to scroll to top of child. The only way around this would be to limit the `max-height` of modal dialogue and make its `.modal-body` scrollable. Your solution does not meet the first requirement of the question.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback. Edited my answer. I think, still it could be a nice solution for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way of achieving this without having to write a bunch of CSS overrides or other custom CSS, basically using just the stock bootstrap classes and adding one extra HTML  element to control the height.

### CSS (Not Needed see below)

```
.modal > .row{
    flex: 1;
}
```

### HTML (Updated see below)

```
<div id="dialogBox" class="modal fade d-flex">
    <div class="row justify-content-center"> <!-- Vertically Align Modal -->
        <div class="modal-dialog align-self-center" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Then to use:

---

### JS

```
$("#dialogBox").modal('show');
```

### OR HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialogBox">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

There is probably a way to achieve the desired result using only the bootstrap `.row`, `.col` and `flex-XXX` classes but I was unable to get that to work.

One last note, you might have to add: `<body class="d-flex">` to get everything to work depending on the rest of your CSS.

### UPDATE

---

There is a way to achieve this using only bootstrap classes, `h-100` and `w-100`:

```
<div id="dialogBox" class="modal fade d-flex">
    <div class="row justify-content-center w-100"> <!-- Vertically Align Modal -->
        <div class="modal-dialog align-self-center" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
::ng-deep{
    .modal-body{
        padding: 0.25rem;
        width: 600px !important;
    }
    .modal-content {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
        width: 600px !important;
      }
}
```