# Bootstrap modal for confirmation always open at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Bootstrap modal to show a confirmation message. But while deleting content from bottom of the page, the confirmation message stays at the top of the page anyway.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input id="deleteGroupId" type="hidden" value="" />
                <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-confirm-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide a fiddle or codepen

Comment: `#deleteModal { display: none; }` ?

Comment: you can try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053408/vertically-centering-bootstrap-modal-window)